# rspec eq "double quotes"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

How can I get this spec working

Actual result:

```
expected: [#<Department id: 1, user_id: 1,  ...
     got: [#<Department id: 1, user_id: "1",  ...
```

This is my spec:

```
 describe "GET department list" do
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      @current_user = Fabricate(:user_with_active_account_and_departments) 
      # creates a user with 10 departments
      @current_user.confirm! 
      # or set a confirmed_at inside the factory.
      # Only necessary if you are using the confirmable module
      sign_in @current_user
    end

    it "assigns all departments of current_user to @departments" do
      get :departments, {id: @current_user}
      assigns(:users_departments).should eq (@current_user.departments)
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your column type in `departments` table from string to integer:

```
def self.up
  change_column :departments, :user_id, :integer
end

def self.down
  change_column :departments, :user_id, :string
end
```